# Mount EFS volume getting `Unable to mount volumes for pod...` error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-efs

I created PersistentVolume (with EFS storage) and PersistentVolumeClaim. When deployed with helm, status says it's `Bound`. So I think those two resources/objects are good. But when I try to mount the volume to container (in Deployment yaml), I am getting error in deployment and the pod gets stuck in `ContainerCreating` status.

`Unable to mount volumes for pod ...: timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod`

Comment: Have you created storage class for EFS and do you have efs broker working?

Comment: This is where I am not sure about with EFS if I need to create the storage class and efs provisioner(aka broker). With other storage I don't need to define the storage class and efs provisioner. I thought that is done on the host side. So do you mean, if I use EFS, I will need to create charts for PV, PVC, StorageClass and the deployment for the efs broker/provisioner?

Comment: @Crou This example did not use StorageClass - https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/amazon/efs_storage.html

Comment: I was not aware of this method, I do not know if this works. The only ones I know of are using [efs-provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/aws/efs).